# Compare geographical distributions of prevalences

Tags: spatial, prevalence

I would like to ask you what statistical method should be used to compare two prevalence distributions.

My problem is the following: I have two prevalences of two diseases A and B (non-exclusive) per 100,000 inhabitants for each region (n=100) of a country, and my question is to know if there is an association in the distribution of these prevalences in the different regions.

I have made choropleth maps which visually are different, but I would like to know if there is a statistical method that could be used in this case.

Comment: At a minimum, you need information about how the prevalences were estimated.  What can you tell us about that?

Comment: These are standardized prevalences calculated from national health insurance databases.